# String To Title Case with Lower Case Conjunctions

Tags: c#, regex

I want to take the string `the lord of the rings` and Title Case it to `The Lord of the Rings`.

---

However the built in `.ToTitleCase()` function capitalizes every word. `The Lord Of The Rings`.

I want to use the English rules here and Lower Case `of` and `the` and other conjunctions.

https://english.stackexchange.com/a/34

---

**C#**

```
string title = "the lord of the rings";

TextInfo textinfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
title = textinfo.ToTitleCase(title);
```

http://rextester.com/KDOOG71862

Comment: It is not supported in .NET, so you will have to write your own method (or find some package on the web).

Comment: You will have to 1st find a set of rules and then write a function that implements it. The latter is rather simple but the 1st is not. I find the answers in the link all wrong by my standards; e.g.: Nobody even mentions 'verbal expressions' which consist of a verb and a prepostion that alters the meaning of the verb and therefore should be capitalized. This is hard to implement, though, e.g.: 'Working On a Building' but 'Standing on the Moon'.

Comment: @Wikto: You beat me to it. Wow, I had completely forgotten I had posted my code before, thanks a lot for pointing it out -. I have appended the current version..